# VIM -- can I use Global Command to filter on two different conditions?

Tags: vim

I have a file that looks like this:

```
    'description': 'US RTS'
    'sgv:activationStatus': true
    'sgv:assignedSegments': ['segments:16c...
    'sgv:created': 2019-09-25T12:31:36.088-04:00
    'sgv:createdBy': '203796'
    'sgv:lastModified': 2020-08-11T15:19:39.230-04:00
...
```

I want to remove all the lines that contain 'sgv:' EXCEPT for the ones that also contain 'assignedSegments'.
I can do it like this:

```
:g!/assignedSegments/s/sgv:.*/& DELETE/
:g/DELETE/d
```

But I think that there may be a more elegant way to do it in a one-liner. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be what you want:

```
:g/sgv:/v/assignedSegments/d
```

From `help :g`

```
                                                                E147
When the command is used recursively, it only works on one line.  Giving a
range is then not allowed. This is useful to find all lines that match a
pattern and do not match another pattern:
        :g/found/v/notfound/{cmd}
This first finds all lines containing "found", but only executes {cmd} when
there is no match for "notfound".
```

Comment: You can use `:g` and/or `:v` together as of Vim 8.0.0630

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. A friend also suggested "negative lookaround" which works, but not as pretty: :g/mgnl:\(assignedSegments\)\@!/d